# Javascript filters - how to change

Tags: javascript, html, list, filter

I am trying to add a portfolio project to more than one category, can anyone help?

Here is the list of categories:

```
                <ul>
                    <li><a data-filter="*" href="#" class="active">Logo Design</a></li>
                    <li>/</li>
                    <li><a data-filter=".web" href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                    <li>/</li>

                </ul>
            </div>
```

To add the project into 1 category I simply type:

```
 <div class="span4 wallpaper">
```

How would i add this to 2 categories (logo design and web design)?

Comment: It totally unclear what you're talking about. What is your environment, do you use some framework? If not, explain how "*simply typing adds a project to a category*".

Comment: Please could you explain in more detail, maybe add a jsfiddle

Comment: No worries, sorted it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="span4 logo web ">
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the name of the filter after `<span4>`.
E.g. `<span4 web anything else>`

Answer (score 1):

There is no complex coding here, just add the name of the filter one after the other  `<span4 web branding` etc.